# Link to another cell of another worksheet by cell value?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have 2 worksheets in the PHPExcel generated file:

```
state:
  - id: 1
    title: New York
  - id: 2
    title: California
  ...
city:
  - id: 987
    title: Los Angeles
    state_id: 2
  ...
```

Basically each worksheet is a database table and the tables are associated with each other via row IDs.

I searched around and found I can link to another cell of another worksheet by something like this:

```
$sheet -> getCell('D9') -> getHyperlink() -> setUrl("sheet://'state'!A1");
```

Which would link the cell `D9` of the current $sheet to A1 of sheet `'state'`.

But that's a static link between cells, not actual **data**.

My question is if there's some way to make the hyperlink link to the cell by its value, something like this:

```
$sheet -> getCell('D9') -> getHyperlink() -> setUrl("sheet://'state'!E=2");
```

So it would link to the first cell from column `E` in worksheet `'state'`, whose value is `2`.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: First you need to ask how you might do this in MS Excel, or even if it's possible in MS Excel

Comment: As a suggestion that might help, MS Excel has a HYPERLINK() function, where you could use Excel function logic to do a lookup (using VLOOKUP(), INDIRECT(), etc) and build the link reference dynamically